# Java Array Equality vs Array Content Equality

Tags: java, arrays, double, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm not sure if I'm just not seeing a blatant answer of if I've been wrong about an important part of this programming language this whole time.

In short, I've got code that contains an array of doubles called "buckets". My code needs to parse this array index-by-index, check its value, and store in a new array called "finalVals" the last 5 values. The buckets array will contain about 100 values, most of which are zeros and are not needed. A sequence of 5 consecutive zeros will imply the end of the data that I need. So I need to return the last 5 values in buckets where the values are all non-zeros. This is stored in the array called "nonZeros".

```
lastVal = new double[5]; // A global variable already declared but not set
double nonZeros[] = new double[5]; // A local variable
int numberOfZeros = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
    double val = buckets[i];
    if (val == 0) {
        System.out.println("Encountered a zero.");
        numberOfZeros++;
        lastVal[0] = lastVal[1];
        lastVal[1] = lastVal[2];
        lastVal[2] = lastVal[3];
        lastVal[3] = lastVal[4];
        lastVal[4] = val;
    }
    else if (val != 0) {
        System.out.println("Did not encounter a zero.");
        numberOfZeros = 0;
        lastVal[0] = lastVal[1];
        lastVal[1] = lastVal[2];
        lastVal[2] = lastVal[3];
        lastVal[3] = lastVal[4];
        lastVal[4] = val;
        nonZeros = lastVal; // This is where the problem was
    }
    prettyPrintArrays(lastVal,nonZeros);
    if (numberOfZeros == 5) { break; }
}
return nonZeros;
```

The problem was in the last set. The if conditions do indeed properly detect whether or not val was 0 (or really 0.0). And keeping the last 5 values in lastVal works. However, when that non-working line is executed, the code behaves as if nonZeros became a pointer that simply pointed to lastVal. The nonZeros array ALWAYS stored the same values as lastVal from there on out, even when zeros were encountered in val. It was my understanding that these variables are independent. So I was expecting nonZeros to only hold the same values as lastVal in cases when we encountered a non-zero. And the function would always just return the last 5 values of buckets before 5 consecutive zeros were encountered.

The solution was to replace that problematic line with code that sets the contents of nonZeros individually just as I did for lastVal. So am I missing something obvious in my code here that is always setting nonZeros to lastVal? Or am I misunderstanding what nonZeros = lastVal; actually does?

Comment: Where is lastVal defined? Is that finalVals?

Comment: Unless a new is used to create a new instance of an object, using the equals is essentially "pointing" to the same object. In this case, the object is the array. i.e. double [] aVal = new double[4]; double[]aVal2 = aVal are "pointing" to the exact same object instance. Changing the value will affect both aVal and aVal2 since they are essentially referencing the same object.

Comment: @lordoku I apologize, I accidentally defined it as finalVals in the first line of code. I have made the code change to correct this, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you did,

```
nonZeros = lastVal;
```

You assigned the reference of lastVal to nonZeros (and yes, *nonZeros became a pointer that simply pointed to lastVal*). That's not a copy. You could use [`System.arraycopy((Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) like

```
System.arraycopy(lastVal, 0, nonZeros, 0, nonZeros.length);
```

Comment: Also, you could do nonZeros = lastVal.clone()

Comment: I thought Java always uses pass-by-value. Does this only apply to arrays themselves and not the contents within the arrays? If these arrays were actual instances of the java.util.Arrays class, would a nonZeros = lastVal have worked?

Comment: @rshaw Java is *always* pass-by-value. But the value of an Object type (including arrays) is a reference. It would have worked to change the reference of `nonZeros` to that of `lastVal`.